# Zend Form : setValue directly in a view

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-form

does it possible to use the setValue method on a Zend form element in a view ?
I try to do this but it give me duplicate field... My code :

```
<?php echo $this->form->str_bloc->renderViewHelper(); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->str_bloc->setValue(3); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->str_bloc->renderErrors(); ?>
```

With this, I have two field, one with default value, one with the value set with the methode. When I remove the first line, nothig appear.

Answer (score 0):

Remove "echo" from line where you setting the value and move this line:

```
<?php $this->form->str_bloc->setValue(3); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->str_bloc->renderViewHelper(); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->str_bloc->renderErrors(); ?>
```

Comment: I have two select list, one with default value, one with the set value

Comment: The code above should render form element only once. Maybe you have another code which render this element again? Try to comment those line and check, if this element shows.